# Chrome differences on localhost and server

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have different visual for localhost and remote site of same code. I don't know why local Chrome is displaying my site completely different:

This is http://beta.cliffbase.com
http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/2477/b557ecb80f7644c9a7893c9.png

And this is my local environment running from VS2010 as localhost
http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/3241/5786958214d64aaba236931.png

You can see that menu and left information items have different paddings and heights.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: Are you COMPLETELY sure that the css file doesn't differ from that in local?

Comment: have you checked all the CSS/JS files are  definitely being loaded and there are no errors loading 1 file from the local env due to url changes (see the network tab in the dev console).  Also check the console for any JS errors in case there is style changes occuring there and a JS error could be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found cause of problem. It is padding/margin of @font-face generated by Font Squirrel. I had to change to Cufon to keep all sizes same. Works fine now.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome allows you to set the Zoom for a webpage independently for local sites and sites on the internet. In my case, this was the reason why my webpage looked different if I used http://localhost:8080/mypage.jsp v/s http://172.20.35.40:8080/mypage.jsp. I reset the zoom to 100% when I was using `localhost` and now both the views are identical.

NOTE: I know this is a really old thread and the the OP already has a solution to *his* issue. But this shows up as the first search result when you google why Chrome shows the same page differently using localhost v/s using IP address. Thought this might help someone in a situation similar to mine.

Comment: Similar issue:  Page zoom is different in Chrome for "localhost" versus everything else.   Read something about Chrome now defines 100% zoom as what we used to call 125%; not sure if read that correctly.  Seems like "localhost" gets old 100% and does not respond at all to change in zoom.  Chetan -- how can zoom on "localhost" be changed independently?

Comment: Just now, I asked this as a question on StackOverflow, so please answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048040/chrome-browser-has-different-zoom-size-for-localhost-versus-all-other-web-site