# Chrome browser has different zoom size for "localhost" versus all other web-sites

Tags: google-chrome, browser, localhost

In Chrome, "localhost" is not responding to the global zoom.

In my Chrome browser, a page served from "localhost" has a different zoom than all other web-sites.  Furthermore, use of "settings" to globally change the zoom percentage affects all sites except not "localhost".  Interestingly, even "file://" responds to the global zoom, but the same set of files acts differently when served as "localhost".

I read something about Chrome switching things so what used to be 125% is now called 100%; can anyone confirm that?  To me, it looks like "localhost" gets the old fashioned version of 100% (so, no extra 25% zoom).

I am using Chrome on a Mac.

By the way, this happens regardless of whether the following "meta" is included in the html  section.  The value of "initial-scale" has no affect.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.00">
```

My question is: Can I change the zoom of "localhost" so that either (a) it responds in sync with the global zoom, or (b) "localhost" is affected individually?

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out.  My mistake was that I had been ignoring a local zoom opportunity to get at the global zoom.

I was doing the following adjustment in Chrome; this sets the global zoom level:
    (3 dot menu) -> Settings -> Appearance -> Page Zoom

The problem went away when I did the following simple thing; which sets zoom just for the current site:
    (3 dot menu) -> Zoom

Apparently, I had used that control on "localhost" months or years ago, and the value persisted until now. Apparently, a site that has had its "zoom" level changed in this "local" way will subsequently not react to changes at the "global" level.

Comment: interesting . Should a site be written/ created at 100% and enable user to reduce or expand to their preferences..or do devs set the %zoom for the user.?

Comment: Zoom is not related to web page design.  After your page has rendered, a person looking at the page and having impaired vision can magnify the page using zoom; this magnification does not affect layout.  For all pages, the <meta> tag described by my original question should be included; this states that the device should apply its actual physical pixel width and height as the effective width and height.  The page designer then uses responsive design to adapt a page to the various possibilities of width.

Comment: Lol I just got bit by this as well. I feel silly that I did not realize that Chrome persists the zoom level per hostname. To make matters worse it isn't unusual for me to accidentally zoom in/out with my mouse. :D